# Searching word in a text file

Tags: livecode

How to reduce time by this code?
TE is the variable that contains my text (contains more than 20000 lines)
and s is my search word.

```
repeat with x = 0 to the number of lines in TE
      if line x of TE contains s then
         put line x-1 of TE & cr & line x of TE & cr & line x+1 of TE & cr & cr after dataarray
      end if 
   end repeat
```

This code works fine, but it take too much time.
How to reduce time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid the `repeat with` syntax as much as possible. Instead, use the `repeat for each`syntax:

```
put 0 into myLineNr
repeat for each line myLine in myData
  // update counter
  add 1 to myLineNr
  if myLine contains mySearchString then
     // store data in new variable
     put line myLineNr - 1 of myData & cr & myLine & cr & line myLineNr + 1 of myData & cr & cr after myNewData
  end if 
end repeat
```

I have changed the script to allow for duplicate lines. This requires a counter, but using a counter is still faster than using the `repeat with` control structure.

Comment: If there are duplicate lines in myData, the lineOffset function will only find the first one, unless you use the optional third parameter, linesToSkip.

Comment: Yep, that's true Devin. I'll update the code when I have a moment.

Comment: Thanks @ Mark and Devin